# plt.bar error with TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

My data looks like

```
    print(core_df2)

                         dispatch_patch
    date                  
    2019-11-13 18:28:00              50
    2019-11-13 18:29:00             450
    2019-11-13 18:30:00             825
    2019-11-13 18:31:00            1450
    2019-11-13 18:32:00            1725
    ...                             ...
    2019-11-13 19:26:00            4850
    2019-11-13 19:27:00            4875
    2019-11-13 19:28:00            5175
    2019-11-13 19:29:00            4314
    2019-11-13 19:30:00               6

    [63 rows x 1 columns]
```

Im trying to make bar plot and have problem.

If I draw the bar plot like this

```
    core_df2.plot.bar() #I can see the plot
```

but I use like below, it show error message.

```
    37 plt.figure(figsize=(17,12))
    ---> 38 plt.bar(core_df2)
         39 

    TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'
```

and also, If I use

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(17,12))
    plt.plot(core_df2)

    #I can see the plot.
```

it seems plt.bar cannot get the time index as x axis value.

do you know how I can solve the problem?

thank you

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot.bar(x, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, *, align='center', data=None, **kwargs)`  

You need to specify some value for height.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. yes I should specify the X value. but dont know how to get the time( it is index) from my dataframe. I can get the Y value like core_df2['dispatch_patch'] but dont know how to get the 'date' which is index. cannot get x from core_df2['date']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass **dataframe.index** and then the column name.

```
plt.bar(core_df2.index, core_df2['dispatch_patch'])
```

Answer (score 0):

@dy jang, As per your comment, you can get date as dataframe column by using below code:

```
    core_df2.reset_index()
```

This will create a new column with header 'index' in your dataframe. Then, you can use it as:

```
    plt.bar(core_df2['index'],core_df2['dispatch_patch'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a way to convert the datetime index into datetime type: use the pd.DatetimeIndex() function provided by pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
core_df["year"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(core_df.date).year
core_df["month"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(core_df.date).month
core_df["weekday"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(core_df.date).date
```

on the plotting part i don't know yet,but these should help you with the date data type being of object.

Comment: @dy jang also could you please assist me with the download link for the file will be really  helpful. Thank you.